# since Singleton Design Pattern will instantiate only one object, how many objects are created in the below program?

Tags: java, singleton

```
//SingletonObject.java

package Test;

public class SingletonObject {

    private SingletonObject() {

    }

    private static SingletonObject instance = new SingletonObject();
    private static SingletonObject instance1 = new SingletonObject();

    public static SingletonObject getInstance(){
        return instance;

    }

    public static SingletonObject getInstance1(){
        return instance1;
    }

    public void showMessage(){
        System.out.println("Hello World !!! ");
    }

    public void dispMsg(){
        System.out.println("Hai");
    }

}

//SingletonObjectDemo.java

package Test;

public class SingletonObjectDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //SingletonObject obj = new SingletonObject();

        SingletonObject obj = SingletonObject.getInstance();
        obj.showMessage();

        SingletonObject obj1 = SingletonObject.getInstance1();
        obj1.showMessage();
        obj1.dispMsg();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of implementing a singleton one way I usually use is  :

```
public static SingletonObject getInstance()
{
   if ( instance == null )
   {
      instance = new SingletonObject();
   }
   return instance;

}
```

and make your default constructor private:

```
private SingletonObject()
{
  //optional code
}
```

With this you are guaranteed to return only one instance of SingletonObject

Comment: Using an `enum` is a simpler way to define an singleton in a `final class` with a `private` constructor.

Comment: Ok. But enum is used to enumerate a range of values usually. What if my singleton has to behave like a class?

Comment: an `enum` is a class. The range of values can be just one.

Answer (score 1):

**Two**. Because your `Singleton` isn't properly implemented (you have local access to the constructor *and* the instances should be `final`). You could change that like,

```
private static final SingletonObject instance = new SingletonObject();
private static final SingletonObject instance1 = instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to define a singleton is to use an `enum`

```
public enum SingletonObject {
    INSTANCE;

    public void showMessage(){
        System.out.println("Hello World !!! ");
    }

    public void dispMsg(){
        System.out.println("Hai");
    }
}
```

If you want to define two objects like you do in your example, you can give it another enum value.